# Google Analytics not tracking transactions

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm having trouble getting Google Analytics to track transactions for commerce. Here's the code I'm generating on my order confirmation page.

I don't know how to debug this either, I can't find information on how to get error codes out of google's js. I'd run it in firebug's console if I could. At this point I'm stuck on how to proceed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-########-#']);
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.mydomain.com']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


    _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
      '117',           // order ID - required
      'StoreName.com',  // affiliation or store name
      '35.96',          // total - required
      '0',           // tax
      '0',              // shipping
      '',       // city
      '',     // state or province
      ''             // country
    ]);
    _gaq.push(['_addItem',
      '117',           // order ID - required
      '1',           // SKU/code - required
      '1 Pack',        // product name
      'Catagory5',          // catagory   
      '35.96,          // unit price - required
      '1'               // quantity - required
    ]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
  })();
</script>
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Found a typo after unit price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingEcommerce.html) on Google Code. It provides an example of what your trying to do.

Comment: I'm using Google's newer async methods, but the ideas are the same. I'm currently doing the 3 steps that are required and listed on that page.

Comment: Your code looks good compared with the Google examples. You did turn eCommerce tracking on? :+) Also, did the non-async code work for you?

Comment: I will swap it out and check.

Comment: I was rebuilding my code to use the older system, and I found a typo.